# intellij doesnt recognize lombok generated methods from @Data annotation

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

I'm using IntelliJ 2018.3.

I have Lombok plugin installed, and I have Annotation Processing enabled.
The plugin version is the latest as well.

The problem is that Intellij doesn't recognize the generated methods from lombok.

Gradle build is passing so the problem is in IntelliJ.

How can I fix that problem :) ?

Comment: Please report an issue on plugin vendor tracker: https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues

Comment: Which version of the Lombok Plugin are you using? I have v0.23-2018.3 installed with my IntelliJ 2018.3.3 and the generated methods are recognized.

That being said, in the past when I have had similar issues with plugins, one of the below usually resolved the issue:

1. Restarting IntelliJ after plugin install and enabling the annotation processor
2. Invalidate Cache and Restart IntelliJ